# Electron App to stream webcam to RTMP server?

Tags: windows, electron, rtmp

I want to build a dekstop-App which can stream the Webcam-source to a RTMP-server.
I already build a native App which does this on mobile devices (Android and iOS) with the videocamera. Now I want that same thing to do in a desktop-App. I cannot figure out how to achieve this. Is this even possible directly; webcam source to rtmp?

Comment: Since you can extend electron with C or C++, Electron can do anything any other desktop application can do.

Comment: U know a package to use for this @szatmary?

Comment: I would recommend you start by googling "electron rtmp"

Comment: First thing I did and the reason to ask here , while there are no useful results